# Adding Slides to Nivo Slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

I am trying to add new slides to Nivo slider which is on a Wordpress install. The slider is not installed as a plugin and it's custom post types which let it know which images to use. I have uploaded all images (they are client logos) to the relevant custom post types but Nivo slider wont append the images to the existing slides.

Where do I find the settings for Nivo slider to change the number of slides it displays?

Many thanks

Billy

Comment: "The slider is not installed as a plugin"...huh?

Comment: confusing I know. I am working on a site which was built by another developer. The Nivo slider software is there but has not been added to Wordpress as a normal plugin.

Comment: thing is, I can see all the working parts in the themes php files. It just wont update with the new images. All images are custom post types in Wordpress. The code:

Comment: <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'logo_slider', 'order' => 'ASC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>